# Eclipse Scout Neon open search panel manually

Tags: eclipse-scout, search-form

I would like to open search panel on TablePage manually. I would like to know how to open it on page with search form.

I am looking for programing solution for clicking on magnifying glass button :

[image]

Is this possible, or java-script open this panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a large data set and want the user to enter a search criteria before the data gets loaded, you can set `getConfiguredSearchRequired` to true. This will open the search form automatically when the table page is displayed and will ask the user to enter a search criteria.

If you just want to open or close the search form programmatically, you can use `getTable().getTableControl(SearchFormTableControl.class).setSelected(true/false);`